# Syntax for column values for same period of last year in SSRS report

Tags: date, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am generating a report where I SUM price and cost values per month. I would like to show the same defined time period - 1 year. I'm not clear how to nest this. Would I use a case when statement?

My terrible example.

```
select month, cost, price from table1 where (define months here in SSRS parameter filter)
```

I'd like to see:

```
select month, cost, price, lastyearcost, lastyearprice FROM table1 where (define months here in SSRS parameter filter)
```

I know that I should be using some variant of GETDATE() -1, but will this include the data range parameters passed when running the report? How do I select the column of cost apply the date filter and then get the result of cost for that period last year?

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: so if somone passes in 10/14/2016 would you get data from 10/14/2015-10/14/2016? Also, is there an actual date column or just a month column and a year column?

Comment: Essentially I'd like for them the year and month range in the date parameter.select 2017 and month range from 1 to 4. Then show me the cost and price values for that period, in addition show the price and cost values from 2016 months 1 - 4.

Comment: ok that makese sense. Do you have a dateColumn in your datasource or just years and months?

Comment: The parameter will be passed as year = @fiscalyear which would be 2016 or 2017. Then month = ATmonth  which would be a list of all twelve months in the calendar year.

Comment: I have joined my date dimension table. So I have all available options as far as dates

Comment: is the months parameter a single parameter that is then a comma seperated string? or is there a minMonth and maxMonth parameter? This is important for your proc / where clause

Comment: I'm going to do a minmonth and maxmonth parameter. I think that's best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `DATEPART()` with the correct nesting and pairing.

```
select 
    month, 
    cost, 
    price, 
    lastyearcost, 
    lastyearprice 
FROM table1 
where 
    --this is limiting the data to the year passed in, and the previous year
    (datepart(year,DateColumn) = @YearParam or datepart(year,DateColumn) = @YearParam-1)
    and 
    --this is limiting the months to the two parameters you pass in as integers
    (datepart(month,DateColumn) >= @minMonthParam and datepart(month,DateColumn) <= @maxMonthParam)
```

**TEST DATA**

See the D[EMO HERE](http://rextester.com/WHDSUG99659)

```
declare @table1 table (DateColumn date)
insert into @table1 (DateColumn)
values
('1/1/2016'),
('2/1/2016'),
('3/1/2016'),
('4/1/2016'),
('5/1/2016'),
('6/1/2016'),
('7/1/2016'),
('8/1/2016'),
('9/1/2016'),
('10/1/2016'),
('11/1/2016'),
('12/1/2016'),
('1/1/2017'),
('2/1/2017'),
('3/1/2017'),
('4/1/2017'),
('5/1/2017')

declare @YearParam int = 2017
declare @minMonthParam int = 2
declare @maxMonthParam int = 5

select 
    DateColumn
FROM @table1 
where 
    (datepart(year,DateColumn) = @YearParam or datepart(year,DateColumn) = @YearParam-1)
    and 
    (datepart(month,DateColumn) >= @minMonthParam and datepart(month,DateColumn) <= @maxMonthParam)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it inline in the select instead of as the where clause? I could obviously create a view and stage this data before selecting via SSRS. So if I did it that way how could I structure the syntax inline with the select clause?

Comment: @JoeResler, That would yield different results... and wouldn't limit the dataset being returned it would only NULL the rows where the condition isn't met. Usually I write a stored procedure for this that accepts my SSRS parameters instead of having the TSQL in the RDL itself. So, your dataset in your RDL is a stored procedure, giving you greater flexibility in my opinion